# JPA and Hibernate: compare only time portions of timestamps

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm using Hibernate through JPA and I need to filter records by the time portion of their `Date` property .

```
public class Foo {
    Date getDateTime() {
        // Returns a date and time value.
    }
}

Time startTime = ...;
Time endTime = ...;

TypedQuery<Foo> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT foo FROM Foo foo where :startTime <= foo.dateTime AND foo.dateTime <= :endTime", Foo.class);
query.setParameter("startTime", startTime);
query.setParameter("endTime ", endTime);
```

Of course this will not work because you can't directly compare a `Date` and a `Time`. If this were a SQL query, then I would use a few DBMS-specific date functions to compare them, but how do you compare a Date and a Time in JPA?

Comment: Your working with java.sql.Time?

Comment: Just to clarify ...you want to query records that have a datetime column, but only compare against the hh:mm:ss.SSS component of that column. Or said another way, "give me all records that occurred during a time of the day". Correct?

Comment: @kaliatech The former is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a Native Query and then leverage the database specific functions you are familiar with.  Once you have the Native Query you could convert the `java.sql.Time` objects to longs and execute it.

[EntityManager API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

For example if you were using Oracle.

```
            long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long startTimeMillis = (startTime.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY)/1000;
    long stopTimeMillis = (endTime.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY)/1000;
    entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(
                    "select * from foo where to_number(to_char(date_time, 'sssss')) between ?1 and ?2", Foo.class)
            .setParameter(1, startTimeMillis)
            .setParameter(2, stopTimeMillis).getResultList();
```

The actual query will vary depending on your database flavor, however creating a NativeQuery should allow you to leverage the underlying vendor functions specific to your database.

Another way to approach this challenge would be to create a view that includes a column containing the time portion of the column with the date datatype.  This would allow you to leverage the underlying database technology in a manner that is transparent in the code.  Once this column is setup, you would establish the proper where clause in your Query.

Comment: If 'sssss' returns seconds from midnight (not milliseconds), then I think you need to divide startTimeMillis and stopTimeMillis by 1000 before inserting them as parameters of the query.

Comment: @kaliatech Thats a good point, I certainly missed that.  Is there a way to tell Oracle to return milliseconds from midnight?

Comment: I don't know of any easy way using to_char.  Here's [one possible solution](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_date_format_hundredths_second.htm) though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JPA you can use 
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) 
It will return only Time part of the TIMESTAMP.
Like:
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) 
Date getDateTime()

Answer (score 1):

There is not an any easy or standardized way to compare against only the time (or date) component of an existing datetime/timestamp column using JPA2. Options:

1. **Use a native query**.  [kmb385's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181715/123378) works if you need seconds precision (not milliseconds).  I think a more common native SQL method is to use CAST or EXTRACT to compare against only the time components.
2. **Add another column to the table/view that holds only the time component** of the datetime and do your comparisons using that.  You would likely also add another field to Foo with the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)` annotation.

Comment: Just curious why wouldn't my method match just the time portion?

Comment: I originally misunderstood what the 'sssss' formatting does in Oracle. I looked it up just now, and agree, your answer would work as intended (with one small correction which I'll note in a comment). I'll edit my answer now to avoid confusion.